# Regulating user-daemons from listening on unprivileged ports (preventing server spoofing)?

Tags: security, services, daemon, socket, port

If I have a port >1024 but that I want to reserve to one executable how can I ensure that no other executable can open and listen to a socket on that port?

```
/usr/bin/foo_srv -p 8080
/usr/bin/bar_srv -p 8080
```

I only want `foo_srv` to be able to listen on `:8080` how do I prevent `bar_srv` from server spoofing? I know I can use SSL and the like, but is there anything Linux provides that can do this?

Comment: I've never tried this, but maybe SELinux? https://www.rootusers.com/use-selinux-port-labeling-to-allow-services-to-use-non-standard-ports/